# The closure of $X$, a subset of the continuum, $C$, satisfies $\bar{X} = \bar{\bar{X}}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a subset of $C$, the continuum. The closure of $X$, defined by:
$$\bar{X} = X \cup \{ x \in C \mid x\text{ is a limit point of X}\}$$ 
satisfies  $\bar{X} = \bar{\bar{X}}$.

I need to prove this and I have no idea how to do so. Any help would be grateful. Thanks so much.

Comment: It (the proof) depends on your definition of closure. May I ask which one you are using?

Comment: Let $X$ be a subset of $C$. The closure of $X$ is the subset $\bar{X}$ of $C$ defined by: $$ \bar{X} = X \cup \{ x \in C where x is a limit point of X} $$

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof is a bit shorter if you use the notion of an *adherence point of X*, which is, by definition, a point $y$ such that each neighborhood of $y$ intersects $X$. Note that if a point $y$ is in $X$ or is a limit point, then it is an adherence point. And, conversely, if an adherence point of $X$ is not already in $X$, then it must be a limit point of $X$. So the closure of $X$ is just the set of all adherence points of $X$.

To prove your statement, let $y$ be an adherence point of $\bar X$. You have to show that it is an adherence point of $X$, so let $U$ be a neighborhood of $y$. Then $U$ contains an open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ which intersects $\bar X$, thus there is a $z\in V\cap\bar X$. As $V$ is open, it is also a neighborhood of $z$, so it must intersect $X$. This shows that an arbitrary neighborhood of $y$ intersects $X$, so $y$ is an adherence point of $X$

Comment: no, sorry i'm still a bit lost.

Comment: @user1554862: I've completed the proof. See my edit.